# Select and join on dynamic table name

Tags: mysql, select, join

I would like to get all information about every `item`. Items has global variable (here `on_stock`), but every item has also its own property in different table, and that table has the same name as the items type name.

1. select items
2. join its type_id on types table id -> `name`
3. join selected item on `name`.id

Here is the sample:

```
[items]
 id  | on_stock |  type_id
-----+----------+-----------
  1       1        1(=car)
  2       0        1(=car)
  3       1        2(=ship)
  4       0        2(=ship)

[types]
 id |  name
----+--------
  1     car
  2    ship

[car]
 id | top_speed
----+-----------
 1       200
 2       300

[ship]
 id  | color
-----+-------
 3     red
 4     blue
```

expected result:

```
1 on_stock=1 top_speed=200
2 on_stock=0 top_speed=300
3 on_stock=1 color=red
4 on_stock=0 color=blue
```

Please help to achieve this!

Comment: This is exactly why this is not a very good database design. I'd suggest you re-design your tables. This is only the first of many headaches this design will give you.

Comment: @JohnFx This is a redesigned one. Could you show me how would you redesign this?

Comment: @JohnFx If I would store type name in the items table that would make this easier, I know, but this way it is more elegant, isn't it?

Comment: Needs more re-design. A code smell for databases is when A) you need to use dynamic table names in queries to get the job done; or B) you need to modify the database structure when you have new data to add. Let me mock up a quick design that is a little better for this and will server you better. One sec.

Answer (score 0):

If I could not do it in one request, I'll do it in more(1+item types count).

first, I need the required types as array(id=>name):

```
$req_types = array();
    $rs = mysql_query("
        SELECT items.type_id,types.name
        FROM items 
        JOIN types ON items.type_id=type.id 
        GROUP BY items.type_id
        ");
    while($type= mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
        $req_types[$type['id']] = $type['name'];
```

then I need the common and individual item data:

```
$groups = array();     
foreach($req_types as $table)
        {
            $rs = mysql_query("
                    SELECT items.*,$table.*
                    FROM items 
                    JOIN $table ON $table.id=items.id
                    ");
            while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
                $groups[$table][] = $item;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty, but neither is the data structure. Here is a query to do what you want

```
SELECT I.id, I.On_stock, C.top_speed,S.Color
FROM ITEMS I
LEFT JOIN Car C ON (I.ID = C.CarID)
LEFT JOIN Ship S ON (I.ID = S.ShipID)
```

You will have to tweak the query every time you add a new item type, but that is just a downside of this data structure.